# (Class) (Int) and LAG with negative values

Tags: python, sql, window-functions, lag

I am building a little crypto project and have tried various methods to run a test on moving volume average (previous rows) compared to current volume (current row).

I have tried LAG in a case statement testing above and below 0 does not work as LAG treats negative values as positive.  Ie: -2 is greater than -1.

With the help of a previous question here I changed the code to use (Class) (Int) however this treats -2 is greater than -1 also.

LAG:

```
 (case when lag(volume) over (partition by name order by recordid) < volume \
             then '1' \
             when lag(volume) over (partition by name order by recordid) > volume \
             then '0' \
```

(Class) (Int):

```
for x in records:
            rid = (x[0])
            result = int(x[1] > x[2])
            data+= [(result, rid)]
```

Im new to this but having fun none the less. I learn by doing and am learning fast.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Hopefully this Question has sufficient info and meets the criteria for a good question.

Comment: You need to call `int()` on each column, not the result of comparing. `int(x[1]) > int(x[2])`

Comment: It's not LAG that's doing this. The database API is converting all the results to strings. This would happen with any numbers returned in a query.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked.

```
    cursor1.execute("select recordid, cast(mvavgvol as integer), cast(quote_usd_volume_change_24h as integer) from pumped")
    records = cursor1.fetchall()
    
    data= []
    for x in records:
                rid = (x[0])
                result= int(x[2]) > int(x[1])
                data+= [(result, rid)]

cursor2.executemany("UPDATE pumped SET mvavgvolcheck = %s WHERE recordid = %s", (data))

Result:
quote_usd_volume_change_24h mvavgvol    mvavgvolcheck
-33.7011                    7.836209091       0
-31.6161                    1.897163636       0
-40.0176                   -4.020654545       0
```

Prior to the change the last entry result would have been 1.